# when i press get route button i want my javascript variable to get stored in a database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I want my data fetched from google maps api to be inserted into my (mysql) database.i want the data like source_address,destination_address,distance,duration of all the alternative routes to be inserted into my mysql database in just a click of get_route function that i wrote.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10pt;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var source, destination; 
        var directionsDisplay;              // The whole map rendering or displaying.

        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();  // For Availing the Direction Services provided by APIs

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {              //  This acts as a pageload Function    
            new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtSource'));
            new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtDestination'));
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': true });
        });

        function GetRoute() {
            var kolkata = new google.maps.LatLng(22.7383075, 88.454424);  // Center of the Map
            var mapOptions = {              // Setting the View of the Map
                zoom: 7,
                center: kolkata
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);   // Variable for map view

            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);                              // Map view

            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('dvPanel'));  //Panel View

            //------------------------------DIRECTIONS AND ROUTE------------------------------------------------------

            source = document.getElementById("txtSource").value;
            destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;

            var request =                        // variable request
        {                                   // DirectionsService
                origin: source,
                destination: destination,
        provideRouteAlternatives: true,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {                  // RouteService
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
            });

            //-----------------------------DISTANCE AND DURATION----------------------------------------------------

            var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();          // Different Services Provided by APIs
            service.getDistanceMatrix({
                origins: [source],
                destinations: [destination],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false
            }, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                    var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;    //  Distance Calculation From data provide by APIs
                    var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;      //  Duration Calculation From data provide by APIs
                    var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");         // This Variable is for Fetching the Routes distance and displaying it on web page.
                    dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
                    dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
                    dvDistance.innerHTML += "Duration:" + duration;

                } else {
                    alert("Unable to find the distance via road.");
                }
            });
        }                            

    </script>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                Source:
                <input type="text" id="txtSource"  style="width: 200px" />
                &nbsp; Destination:
                <input type="text" id="txtDestination" style="width: 200px" />
                <br />
                <input type="button" value="Get Route" onclick="GetRoute()" />
                <hr />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div id="dvDistance">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="dvMap" style="width: 800px; height: 500px">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="dvPanel" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
</body>
```

Comment: any help is appreciated.thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any PHP code at all?

Comment: You should write your backend script. Use XMLHttpRequest to ajax save but your server is delegated on executing database transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AJAX for this. After getting all the details like `source`, `destination`, `distance` and `duration`, gather and package up all data using AJAX and send them asynchronously to a different page, for example **saveDetails.php** to save all data to your database table.

Here's the AJAX reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

So your JavaScript should be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var source, destination; 
    var directionsDisplay;              // The whole map rendering or displaying.

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();  // For Availing the Direction Services provided by APIs

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {              //  This acts as a pageload Function    
        new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtSource'));
        new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtDestination'));
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': true });
    });

    function GetRoute() {
        var kolkata = new google.maps.LatLng(22.7383075, 88.454424);  // Center of the Map
        var mapOptions = {              // Setting the View of the Map
            zoom: 7,
            center: kolkata
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);   // Variable for map view

        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);                              // Map view

        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('dvPanel'));  //Panel View

        //------------------------------DIRECTIONS AND ROUTE------------------------------------------------------

        source = document.getElementById("txtSource").value;
        destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;

        var request =                        // variable request
    {                                   // DirectionsService
            origin: source,
            destination: destination,
    provideRouteAlternatives: true,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };

        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {                  // RouteService
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });

        //-----------------------------DISTANCE AND DURATION----------------------------------------------------

        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();          // Different Services Provided by APIs
        service.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins: [source],
            destinations: [destination],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
        }, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;    //  Distance Calculation From data provide by APIs
                var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;      //  Duration Calculation From data provide by APIs
                var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");         // This Variable is for Fetching the Routes distance and displaying it on web page.
                dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
                dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
                dvDistance.innerHTML += "Duration:" + duration;

                // Here's your AJAX request
                var httpRequest;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, IE7+ ...
                    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 6 and older
                    httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
                        alert(httpRequest.responseText);
                    }
                };
                httpRequest.open("POST", "saveDetails.php", true);
                httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                httpRequest.send("source=" + source + "&destination=" + destination + "&distance=" + distance + "&duration=" + duration);  

            } else {
                alert("Unable to find the distance via road.");
            }
        });
    }                            

</script>
```

And on **saveDetails.php** page, process your data like this:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['source']) && isset($_POST['destination']) && isset($_POST['distance']) && isset($_POST['duration'])){

        // do your database operations

    }

?>
```

### Edited:

As per your requirement,

> i want to store the distance and duration of multiple alternative routes in the table...and i want my database to be trip(trip_id,source,destination) route(route_id.trip_id,distance,duration) one to many relationship between trip and route. trip_id being the foreign key

Here's the complete solution:

First of all, create two tables named `trip` and `route`. Their structures would be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE trip(
trip_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
source VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
destination VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(trip_id)
);

CREATE TABLE route(
route_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
trip_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
distance VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
duration VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(route_id),
FOREIGN KEY(trip_id) REFERENCES trip(trip_id)
);
```

And now comes to your HTML and JavaScript code,

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10pt;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var source, destination;
    var routeArr = [];
    var directionsDisplay;                                                      // The whole map rendering or displaying.
    var globalResponse;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();                // For Availing the Direction Services provided by APIs

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {              //  This acts as a pageload Function    
        new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtSource'));
        new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtDestination'));
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': true });
    });

    function GetRoute()
    {
        var kolkata = new google.maps.LatLng(22.7383075, 88.454424);  // Center of the Map
        var mapOptions = {                                           // Setting the View of the Map
            zoom: 7,
            center: kolkata
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);   // Variable for map view

        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);                                              // Map view

        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('dvPanel'));             //Panel View

        //------------------------------DIRECTIONS AND ROUTE------------------------------------------------------

        source = document.getElementById("txtSource").value;
        destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;

        var request =                        // variable request
        {                                   // DirectionsService
            origin: source,
            destination: destination,
            provideRouteAlternatives: true,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT
        };

        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status){   // RouteService
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
                /*for (var i = 0; i < response.routes.length; i++) {
                var dr = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
                dr.setDirections(response);
                // Tell the DirectionsRenderer which route to display
                dr.setRouteIndex(i);
                dr.setMap(map);

                // Code ommited to display distance and duration
                }*/

                globalResponse = response;
                routeArr = [];
                for(i=0;i<globalResponse.routes.length;i++){
                    routeArr.push([globalResponse.routes[i].legs[0].distance.text, globalResponse.routes[i].legs[0].duration.text]);
                }

                var s = 'Possible routes are: <br />';
                for(i = 0; i < routeArr.length; ++i){
                    s += "Distance: " + routeArr[i][0] + ", " + "Duration: " + routeArr[i][1] + "<br />";
                }

                document.getElementById("dvDistance").innerHTML = s;
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }

            // Here's the AJAX request
            var httpRequest;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, IE7+ ...
                httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 6 and older
                httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {                           // here the function name that is designed to handle the response
                if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {          //200 OK response code. // 4 is complete response received
                    alert(httpRequest.responseText);
                }
            };
            httpRequest.open("POST", "mapdb.php", true);       // here true means asynchronously server is called,i.e,without page reloading
            httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpRequest.send("source=" + source + "&destination=" + destination + "&routes=" + JSON.stringify(routeArr));

        });

        //-----------------------------DISTANCE AND DURATION----------------------------------------------------

        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();          // Different Services Provided by APIs
        service.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins: [source],
            destinations: [destination],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
        }, function (response, status){
            if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
               /*var distance = globalResponse.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;    //  Distance Calculation From data provide by APIs
                var duration = globalResponse.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;      //  Duration Calculation From data provide by APIs
                var distance = globalResponse.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
                var duration = globalResponse.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
                var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");         // This Variable is for Fetching the Routes distance and displaying it on web page.
                dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
                dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
                dvDistance.innerHTML += "Duration:" + duration;//+ " "+typeof response.routes.length;*/

            }else {
                alert("Unable to find the distance via road.");
            }
        });
    }
</script>  
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                Source:
                <input type="text" id="txtSource"  style="width: 200px" />
                &nbsp; Destination:
                <input type="text" id="txtDestination" style="width: 200px" />
                &nbsp; Travel Mode:
                 <select>
                <option value="1" >Driving</option>
                <option value="2">Cycling</option>
                <option value="3">Transit</option>
                <option value="4"selected>Walking</option>
                </select>
                <br />
                <input type="button" value="Get Route" onclick="GetRoute()" />
                <hr />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div id="dvDistance">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="dvMap" style="width: 800px; height: 500px">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="dvPanel" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, your **mapdb.php** page would be like this:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['source'], $_POST['destination']) && count($_POST['routes'])){
        $routes_array = json_decode($_POST['routes'], true);

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "testdb");
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
             die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        $source = $_POST['source'];
        $destination = $_POST['destination'];
        $query = "INSERT INTO trip(source, destination) VALUES('{$source}', '{$destination}')";
        if($conn->query($query)){

            $trip_id = $conn->insert_id;
            foreach($routes_array as $route){
                $distance = $route[0];
                $duration = $route[1];
                $query = "INSERT INTO route(trip_id, distance, duration) VALUES({$trip_id}, '{$distance}', '{$duration}')";
                $conn->query($query);
            }
            echo "success";
        }else{
            echo "Record couldn't be inserted";
        }

        // Close connection
        $conn->close();
    }

?>
```

Comment: i have to connect to my database within that same scope? can u provide me ur email-id i will be sending u my code

Comment: @SumeetJaiswal I have shared most of the code here. You just have to write your php code in **saveDetails.php** page to insert all the relevant data to your table. What issue you're facing now?

Comment: saveDetails.php :- after making a successful connection with db i am writing this: $trip_id = $_POST['trip_id'];
  $source = $_POST['source'];
  $destination = $_POST['destination'];
  $distance = $_POST['distance'];
  $duration = $_POST['duration'];
   if(isset($_POST['trip_id']) && isset($_POST['source']) && isset($_POST['destination']) && isset($_POST['distance']) && isset($_POST['duration']))
   {
  $sql="INSERT INTO trip values(trip_id,source,destination,distance,duration) VALUES('$trip_id','$source', '$destination', $distance, $duration)";
}

Comment: then this code   $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql); 
  if($result) 
  {
   echo "Successfully updated database";
  } 
  else 
  { 
   die('Error: '.mysqli_error($link));
  }

Comment: i have made a trip table and inserting those data along with trip_id as unique identifier. but i am getting an error such as undefined varaible

Comment: @SumeetJaiswal That's because `$trip_id` is undefined. How you're getting `$_POST['trip_id']` on **saveDetails.php** page? My advice is, make the `trip_id` column of your table auto-incrementable.

Comment: $sql="INSERT INTO trip values(source,destination,distance,duration) VALUES('$source', '$destination', $distance, $duration)"; this will do?          And i have added <html> src code b4 ur given javascript file as in asked question

Comment: @SumeetJaiswal Your query is wrong, it should be `$sql="INSERT INTO trip(source,destination,distance,duration) VALUES('$source', '$destination', $distance, $duration)";`.

Comment: But there is one problem it is storing the distance and duration of single route ,not the multiple routes distance and duration which i am fetching in my gui

Comment: i want to store the distance and duration of multiple alternative routes in the table

Comment: @SumeetJaiswal What do mean by *multiple alternative routes*? You have the source, for example Kolkata, destination, for example Delhi, and the distance and duration. From where did you get alternative routes?

Comment: alternative routes is the other ways(routes) by which we can reach to delhi, it's showing in my html page at right panel ..just chk once

Comment: run the html page which i asked in the question ,it's showing the alternative routes from source to destination

Comment: @SumeetJaiswal Please read the documentation carefully. Since I've provided you the AJAX code, this [section of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Routes) will guide you in the right direction.

Comment: okk i have read this,but if i perform this provideRouteAlternatives: true then google maps returns me alternative routes, and i want to store all the routes related to single getroute() .for example if there is trip(trip_id,src_addr,dest_addr) and route(route_id,trip_id,distance,duration) both the tables are joined by trip_id ,there is one to many relation between them one trip can have multiple routes ,so actually i want to store this.i want to store distance and duration of each route being specified by single trip_id of trip table.

Comment: hey can u guide me from the question that i provided,i have solved the problem of displaying multiple alternative routes but i could'nt insert it into the database,i need something in the ajax request need to be changed @Rajdeep paul

Comment: @SumeetJaiswal Please post your updated code on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) and share the link here.

Comment: actual problem lies is that now the database is not getting connected

Comment: and i want my database to be trip(trip_id,source,destination) route(route_id.trip_id,distance,duration) one to many relationship between trip and route. trip_id being the foreign key

Comment: @SumeetJaiswal I've updated my answer. Please see the **edited** section of my answer. I've tested this code on my system and is working as expected. Let me know whether this works for you as well or not.

Comment: yes it is working.. but in my algorithm i want the values without its unit like there data is with km and duration is with hours and mins for my calculation i need integer or float value.. how is that possible? @Rajdeep paul

Comment: @SumeetJaiswal You change your requirements after each answer/comment. Not good. However, to answer your question, yes, it *is* possible. I'll leave these trivial things to you as homework. Do little bit of research, try to solve the problem and if you still couldn't solve it *then* ask on SO.

Comment: @ Rajdeep paul  yes i have done it.....well u guided me very well . i have created a drop down menu for my modes and gave id for that dropdown but my request is not getting passed to the db through that httpRequest.send command which u have added in my code, onclick event will be done but my db is not running once i do it. can u help in this matter

Comment: @SumeetJaiswal So is it working as you had expected?

Comment: yes ,now i am working with no. of routes, so i have added this line                
                var dvRouteCount = document.getElementById("dvRouteCount");
                dvRouteCount.innerHTML = i;   after creating a div with id=dvRouteCount   but it's not showing how any routes are there for a particular trip_id

Comment: can u give me an idea how can i store no. of routes, actually i have taken the index of for loop been executed, so can u be able tell me how to perform that no. of routes @Rajdeep paul

Comment: hey my last problem is also solved... u helped me alot

Comment: @SumeetJaiswal Glad I could help. Please mark the answer as *accepted* so that it could be useful for future visitors of SO. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Hey can u help me in my last case ,actually here i can do it for any one mode of travel like travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT ,if i want to store data of driving ,walking,cycling also in the db what i have to do? means alongwith storing distance duration data of Transit mode ,i also want to store distance and duration of other modes as well in the same database.this is my last query

Comment: @ Rajdeep Paul ,hey can u answer my this question that if i want the distance and duration of all the travel modes(google.maps.TravelMode.*) in my this map how can i get that? * here means all the modes

Comment: @SumeetJaiswal I cannot edit the existing answer otherwise it would defeat the purpose. If you have different requirement then I suggest you form a separate question and ask.

Comment: @ Rajdeep Paul So, will i form another question,then can u answer?

Comment: hey i have formed another question and posted,please guide me .ur guidance proves fruitful for me @ Rajdeep Paul

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862326/how-can-i-get-distance-and-duration-for-all-travel-modes-like-driving-transit-cy   here is the link for my question asked  @ Rajdeep Paul