# how can i get distance and duration for all travel modes like driving,transit,cycling,walking in my page,and storing the same in db

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I only succeded in displaying and storing the data of a single travel mode but now i want to store the data like distance and duration from all travel modes,here is the code,what changes do i need to perform,thanks in advance
    mapper.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10pt;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var source, destination;
        var routeArr = [];
        var directionsDisplay;                                                      // The whole map rendering or displaying.
        var globalResponse;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();                // For Availing the Direction Services provided by APIs

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {              //  This acts as a pageload Function    
            new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtSource'));
            new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtDestination'));
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': true });
        });

        function GetRoute()
        {
            var kolkata = new google.maps.LatLng(22.7383075, 88.454424);  // Center of the Map
            var mapOptions = {                                           // Setting the View of the Map
                zoom: 7,
                center: kolkata
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);   // Variable for map view

            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);                                              // Map view

            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('dvPanel'));             //Panel View


            //------------------------------DIRECTIONS AND ROUTE------------------------------------------------------

            source = document.getElementById("txtSource").value;
            destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;

            var request =                        // variable request
            {                                   // DirectionsService
                origin: source,
                destination: destination,
                provideRouteAlternatives: true,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status){   // RouteService
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
        {
                    globalResponse = response;
                    routeArr = [];

                    for(i=0;i<globalResponse.routes.length;i++)
        { 

                        routeArr.push([globalResponse.routes[i].legs[0].distance.text, globalResponse.routes[i].legs[0].duration.text]);
                    }
                    var s = 'Possible routes are: <br />';
                    for(i = 0; i < routeArr.length; ++i)
        {

            routeArr[i][0] = routeArr[i][0].trim();
            routeArr[i][0] = routeArr[i][0].substring(0,routeArr[i][0].length-3)
            routeArr[i][1] = routeArr[i][1].split(' ');
            if(routeArr[i][1].length==2)
            {
                routeArr[i][1]=parseInt(routeArr[i][1][0]);
            }
            else
            {
                routeArr[i][1]=parseInt(routeArr[i][1][0])*60 + parseInt(routeArr[i][1][2]);
            }
                        s += "Distance: " + routeArr[i][0] + ", " + "Duration: " + routeArr[i][1] + "<br />";

                    }

                    document.getElementById("dvDistance").innerHTML = s;
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);


                }

                // Here's the AJAX request
                var httpRequest;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, IE7+ ...
                    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 6 and older
                    httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {                           // here the function name that is designed to handle the response
                    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {          //200 OK response code. // 4 is complete response received
                        alert(httpRequest.responseText);
                    }
                };
                httpRequest.open("POST", "mapdb.php", true);       // here true means asynchronously server is called,i.e,without page reloading
                httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                httpRequest.send("source=" + source + "&destination=" + destination + "&sel=" + sel + "&i=" + i + "&routes=" + JSON.stringify(routeArr));

            });

            //-----------------------------DISTANCE AND DURATION----------------------------------------------------

            var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();          // Different Services Provided by APIs
            service.getDistanceMatrix({
                origins: [source],
                destinations: [destination],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false
            }, function (response, status){
                if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                   /*var distance = globalResponse.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;    //  Distance Calculation From data provide by APIs
                    var duration = globalResponse.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;      //  Duration Calculation From data provide by APIs
                    var distance = globalResponse.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
                    var duration = globalResponse.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
                    var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");         // This Variable is for Fetching the Routes distance and displaying it on web page.
                    dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
                    dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
                    dvDistance.innerHTML += "Duration:" + duration;//+ " "+typeof response.routes.length;*/

                }else {
                    alert("Unable to find the distance via road.");
                }
            });
        var sel = document.getElementById('modes').value;                      // which mode the user is preferring

        }
    </script>  
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                Source:
                <input type="text" id="txtSource"  style="width: 200px" />
                &nbsp; Destination:
                <input type="text" id="txtDestination" style="width: 200px" />
                &nbsp; Travel Mode:
                <select id="modes">
                    <option value="driving" >Driving</option>
                    <option value="cycling">Cycling</option>
                    <option value="transit">Transit</option>
                    <option value="walking"selected>Walking</option>
                </select>
                <br />
                <input type="button" value="Get Route" onclick="GetRoute()" />
                <hr />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div id="dvDistance">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="dvMap" style="width: 800px; height: 500px">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="dvPanel" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
</body>
```

```
 mapdb.php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['source'], $_POST['destination'], $_POST['sel'], $_POST['i']) && count($_POST['routes']))
{
    $routes_array = json_decode($_POST['routes'], true);

                                                    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "testdb");
                                                    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

$i = $_POST['i'];
$sel = $_POST['sel'];
    $source = $_POST['source'];
    $destination = $_POST['destination'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO trip(source, destination, mode, num_routes) VALUES('{$source}', '{$destination}', '{$sel}', '{$i}')";
    if($conn->query($query)){

        $trip_id = $conn->insert_id;
        foreach($routes_array as $route){
            $distance = $route[0];
            $duration = $route[1];
            $query = "INSERT INTO route(trip_id, distance, duration) VALUES({$trip_id}, '{$distance}', '{$duration}')";  //distance in km and durtion
            $conn->query($query);
        }
        echo "Sumeet!!!Success";
    }
else
{
        echo "Something went wrong!!! Record couldn't be inserted";
    }

    // Close connection
    $conn->close();
}

?>
```

Comment: in this code only driving is mentioned and distance an duartion of only driving mode is coming but i need to store the distance and duration of all the travel modes available like cycling,transit,walking as well as driving

Comment: @ Rajdeep Paul could you help me in this matter

Answer (score 0):

Change the MODE to Walking , Transit, Bicycling in your request.First check the output using google directions APIs endpoint on your browser.
Walking and Bicycling results are not available for every pair of locations.

Appending the last part of your travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode."Change here".
[enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#traffic-model)
If iteration(loop) is not possible repeat the code thrice.

Comment: Could you show some code highlighting your explanation?